# File not being Created

Tags: java, file

I am creating a file like this (I am sending arg[0] as the name of the file to be created).
No file is created I searched through the source of the project and found nothing, why?

```
import java.io.File;
public class Test {
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        File f=new File(args[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take some effort to write the question neatly and provide adequate information.

Comment: Also, the javadocs are a great resource for learning about what classes do.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html All `java.io.File` does is create an "An abstract representation of file", that means no file is created until you call the method `createNewFile()`

Answer (score 3):

Try with

```
    File f=new File(args[0]);
    f.createNewFile();
```

Comment: While I realize your answer creates the file it doesn't answer the OP's question of "why".

Answer (score 2):

File is just a representation of the *path*. You need to actually open an output stream with that file and write to that for a file to be created.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal.

A `File` is an *abstract object*. It may, or may not, refer to an existing resource on the filesystem.

But since this is 2015, drop `File`, use java.nio.file instead:

```
final Path path = Paths.get(args[0]);
Files.createFile(path);
```

But really, [you shouldn't use `File` in 2015](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks). Seriously. Yes, `.createNewFile()` exists on `File` but... Well, read the page. In short: returns a boolean, need to check the return value, if false, SOL, you can't even diagnose.

---

Edit: a page to learn how to use java.nio.file: [here](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_java.nio.file_API)

(shameless self-advertising for both links, sorry for that)

Answer (score 0):

Executing `new File(...)` does not create a file in the file system.  A `File` object is just a way of representing the path for a file system object that may or may not existing.

The typical way to create a file is to open a `FileOutputStream` or `FileWriter` for the file.  The file is created even if you don't write anything.  Other alternatives are to call `File.createNewFile()` or `File.createTempFile(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just creating file object does not create physical file on disk.Actual file is created with `f.createNewFile()` as explained in below demo

When yo do `File file=new File(args[0]);` file just represents the java object not the file object on file system

Here is demo for basic file create and delete operations

```
 public class FileDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      File f = null;

      try{
         // create new file
         f = new File("test.txt");

         // tries to create new file in the system
           f.createNewFile();

         // deletes file from the system
         f.delete();

      }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: i do not understand negative votes here. Please provide atleast comments so that who is posting can improve in future. Negative vote is more than welcome but without any purpose it does not serve any purpose.